# Drop-down menu not centered on button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why is the drop-down menu not centered on the button?

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/8jpVsXeI2j)

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
#cta {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
 background-color: white;
 width: 50%;
 margin-left: auto; !important;
 margin-right: auto; !important;
 margin-top: 50px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);" id="cta">
    <h1>Welcome! Let's Get Started!</h1>
    <p>Select a map and let the fun begin.</p>

 <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a map!
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#">Dust II</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Mirage</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Inferno</a></li>
     <li class="divider"></li>
     <li class="dropdown-header">More coming soon!</li>
   </ul>
 </div>

</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container is a block element, this means that it will expand to the entire width of *its* container. The button is centered, but the drop-down menu is set to the left-most edge of `.drop-down`.

To fix this, simply set the parent to `inline-block` so it only takes the minimum amount of space required.

```css
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
#cta {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
    background-color: white;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);" id="cta">
    <h1>Welcome! Let's Get Started!</h1>
    <p>Select a map and let the fun begin.</p>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a map!
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Dust II</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mirage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inferno</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">More coming soon!</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Tiny Giant!